# PHP - Attempting to POST to backend and 500 Error returned?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to POST information to my PHP backend in order to create a Stripe customer, but for some reason, my below code returns a 500 error when I visit the .php path. Any idea why? Most of the below is straight out of the Stripe example so I'm not sure why this is happening... (apologies for my lack of PHP knowledge).

**EDIT:**

```
<?php // Create a customer using a Stripe token

// If you're using Composer, use Composer's autoload:
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Be sure to replace this with your actual test API key
// (switch to the live key later)
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("MYLIVEKEY");

if (!isset($_POST['api_version']))
{
    exit(http_response_code(400));
}

// Create Stripe Customer
try {

    $key = \Stripe\EphemeralKey::create(array(
    "customer" => $customerId, 
    "stripe_version" => $_POST['api_version']
        )
    );

   header('Content-Type: application/json');
    exit(json_encode($key));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    exit(http_response_code(500));
}

?>
```

Comment: judging by your exception handling, it can be anything within your `try` block, but it's guesswork without seeing the `create` method.

Comment: Instead of `exit(http_response_code(500));` can you `print_r($e->getMessage())` to see the actual error message ?

Comment: @LongKim When I attempt to print_r I still get a 500 error page with no error message in sight :/

Comment: Did you remove `exit(http_response_code(500));` ? because if you put `print_r` under `exit` it will never be executed.

Comment: @LongKim Yes I did.

Comment: Check your logs and enable error reporting to catch and display. This is a server error.

Comment: What's the PHP version on your server? The short array syntax (`[..]` rather than `array(...)`) will be a parse error if you're using an old version, which would also get you a 500

Comment: @Don'tPanic Interesting - so nothing wrong with the code? Will check my server logs. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe! I don't know anything about Stripe specifically, but I don't see anything obviously wrong from a general PHP code perspective. The array syntax was just one possible explanation I thought of. The logs will be more helpful than my guessing. ;-)

Comment: I know the Stripe API, and I don't think it will trigger a 500 error by itself. You need to check the PHP error log to see the specific reason.

Comment: @Barmar See code edited above :) I was able to tinker with my code and it prints the following error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_response_code() in /var/www/html/myfile.php on line 15 - Any idea why this is occurring?

Comment: "Call to undefined function http_response_code() " - That's related to your PHP version, I'm assuming you're running a PHP version lower than 5.4?

Comment: @Jonathan You would be correct...apparently I'm running 5.3.29 like a sucker!

Comment: No worries, see my new answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comments, I notice you have the following error:

> Call to undefined function http_response_code()

http_response_code() was introduced in PHP 5.4, so I'm assuming you're running a PHP version lower than 5.4?

You can either upgrade your PHP version, or, remove http_response_code() and set your own responses.

**Example:**

```
<?php

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("MYLIVEKEY");

if (!isset($_POST['api_version'])) 
{
    // Manually set your own header:
    header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
    // Do other things here
}

try {

    $key = \Stripe\EphemeralKey::create(array(
        "customer" => $customerId, 
        "stripe_version" => $_POST['api_version']
    ));

   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   exit(json_encode($key));

} catch (Exception $e) {
   // Manually set your own header instead...
   header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
   // Do other things here
}

?>
```